# How to traverse a list which contains many dicts in Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Now,I have a dict in view and want to present in HTML in the form of table:
[image]

and I pass it into context:

```
context['cities']=cities
```

then,render it:

```
render(request,'index.html',context=context)
```

In 'index.html':

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>population</th>
        <th>country</th>
    </tr>
    {% for city in cities%}
    <tr>
        <td>{{city.name}}</td>
        <td>{{city.population}}</td>
        <td>{{city.country}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Unfortunately,it seems that Django template can't support this kind of traverse,so the result can't show successfully as I expected.
"td" tags are empty.

Comment: It should work, can you share your `views.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like that:

```
render(request,'index.html',context={
    "cities": cities
})
```

Also, you can try into your template:

```
    {% for city in cities %}
    <tr>
        {% for key, value in city %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Where `key` will be `name`, `population`, etc